# importing scripts in html: sjcl.hash.sha512 is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an .html file to test importing stuff from another file. The file structure looks like this:

test(is a folder)

ㄴasdf.html

ㄴlib(is a folder)

---ㄴsjcl.js

asdf.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sjcl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="sjcl.hash.sha512.hash(document.getElementsByName('normaltext')[0].value);">
            <p>input password.<br></p>
            <input type="text" name="normaltext" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As for sjcl.js, I copy-pasted the contents here(http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js) into the file lib/sjcl.js.

When I open asdf.html on Firefox, type something in the text box and click "submit", the console says "sjcl.hash.sha512 is undefined", even though it is clearly defined in the sjcl.js file.

I am inclined to think that this is not a problem with sjcl.js, but instead I messed up somewhere along the lines.

What can I do to make sure that the sha512 hash value of what I submit is printed on the console?

Comment: You could've just used the link to the online version instead of essentially downloading it

Comment: @Bálint That would not have changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular version of the sjcl library that you're using doesn't have the code for sha512.

It looks like the developer hasn't updated the compiled package to match the current source code. You'll need to download and compile the repository yourself or use a different library in order to have that functionality. You might also submit an [issue](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues) to encourage the developer to update the compiled library.

Comment: This seemed to be the right. out of sha1.hash, sha256.hash, sha512.hash, only sha256.hash seems to work. Thank you for your answer!